# Progress indication with animation

Tags: java, game, android, animation

I have a game in which the player has to do something within a defined time.

E.g.: the player has 10 seconds to complete a level.

My current code animates an imageview (it's only a horizontal line) when the game starts:

```
progressAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -Settings.screenWidth, 0, 0);
progressAnimation.setDuration(level * 10000);
progressAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
progressAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

progressView = new ProgressView(context);
progressView.startAnimation(progressAnimation);
```

Simultaneously I start a handler:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fireResultActivity(-1); // -1 means, time's up.
    }
}, level * 10000);
```

If the user can finish the game within 10 seconds an activity comes up and congratulates, if they can't another, "fail" activity comes up.

Is it a good practice to use animation to indicate the progress and start a handler simultaneously?

Could you recommend other (better) solution?

Comment: How can I have people answer this question?

Comment: You've got 1 answer already, but check http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All you should be using `setAnimationListener` on animation object. so no need of `Handler`

```
progressAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
       fireResultActivity(-1); // call your method here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

As it has built-in listener for Animation, there is no need to create new thread using handler

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Code Review! Could you explain in your answer why `setAnimationListener` is better than using a handler?

Comment: As its has in-build listener for `Animation` no need to create new thread using handler

Comment: if you would write your explanation in your answer then we can delete the comments

Comment: @Pimgd update answer